# How to align the dimensions of Deconvolution in neural-net?

Tags: neural-networks, convolution

I tried to implement a NetGraph similar to UNet in Mathematica, but I found an error in the dimension.

```
conv[n_] := NetGraph[{
    ConvolutionLayer[n, {3, 3}],
    ConvolutionLayer[n, {3, 3}],
    ConvolutionLayer[n, {3, 3}, "Stride" -> {1, 2}]
    }, {
    NetPort["In"] -> 1 -> 2 -> 3,
    3 -> NetPort["Res"],
    3 -> NetPort["Out"]
    }];

dec[n_] := NetGraph[{
    CatenateLayer[1],
    DeconvolutionLayer[n, {3, 3}, "Stride" -> {1, 2}],
    DeconvolutionLayer[n, {3, 3}],
    DeconvolutionLayer[n, {3, 3}]
    }, {
    NetPort["In"] -> 1,
    NetPort["Res"] -> 1,
    1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> NetPort["Out"]
    }];

NetGraph[<|
  "re" -> ReshapeLayer[{1, 32, 300}],
  "c1" -> conv[32],
  "c2" -> conv[64],
  "m" -> {
    ConvolutionLayer[64, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> "Same"],
    ConvolutionLayer[64, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> "Same"],
    ConvolutionLayer[64, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> "Same"]
    },
  "d2" -> dec[64],
  "d1" -> dec[32],
  "map" -> {
    ConvolutionLayer[16, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> "Same"],
    ConvolutionLayer[16, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> "Same"],
    ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> "Same"]
    }
  |>, {
  NetPort["Input"] -> "re" -> "c1",
  NetPort[{"c1", "Out"}] -> "c2",
  NetPort[{"c1", "Res"}] -> NetPort[{"d1", "Res"}],
  NetPort[{"c2", "Out"}] -> "m",
  NetPort[{"c2", "Res"}] -> NetPort[{"d2", "Res"}],
  "m" -> NetPort[{"d2", "In"}],
  "d2" -> NetPort[{"d1", "In"}],
  "d1" -> "map" -> NetPort["Output"]
  }]
```

[image: The NetGraph]

Then I found that the error occurred in the output dimension of Deconvolution.

```
ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}, "Input" -> {32, 28, 296}, "Stride" -> {1, 2}]
DeconvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}, "Input" -> {32, 26, 147}, "Stride" -> {1, 2}]
```

[image: Dimension failed to align]

I have tried to use the paddingSize and other parameters to adjust it, but it failed to solve this problem.

Is my understanding wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how other languages handle this edge case but in Mathematica, this behaviour is not an error but is expected. Consider this simple example:

```
Partition[{2, 4, 8, 16}, 2]
(* Out: {{2, 4}, {8, 16}} *)

Partition[{2, 4, 8, 16, 32}, 2]
(* Out: {{2, 4}, {8, 16}} *)
```

First, we gave a 4-length list and second a 5-length one, but by default, it's partitioned base on the size of the window, not the input size. You can see the same behaviour with the following code:

```
conv1 = ConvolutionLayer[1, 2, "Input" -> {1, 4}, "Stride" -> 2]
```

[image]

```
conv2 = ConvolutionLayer[1, 2, "Input" -> {1, 5}, "Stride" -> 2]
```

[image]

Even though the input size differs, the output size is the same. In fact, this behaviour is [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvolutionLayer.html) and the formula for calculating the new dimension is also mentioned (the `Floor` function is involved).

If we place your dimension in the formula we see the output dimensions:

```
Floor[{(28 - (3 - 1) - 1)/1 + 1, (296 - (3 - 1) - 1)/2 + 1}]

(* Out: {26, 147} *)
```

If you replace 296 with 295, you'll still get 147 as a new dimension.

Following [`DeconvolutionLayer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeconvolutionLayer.html) formula, we can calculate the output dimensions too:

```
Floor[{1*(26 - 1) + 3, 2*(147 - 1) + 3}]

(* Out: {28, 295} *)
```

You can define the right-side padding in `ConvolutionLayer` to make use of that extra column but as of 13.2, asymmetric padding is not yet implemented for `DeconvolutionLayer`.